# How to setup planning group moveit for dual arm

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I had a self-made dual arm system, want to set up the moveit configuration.

I follow the advice to configure it like this.

```
<group name="left_arm">
    <joint name="left_arm_base_joint" />
   ...
    <joint name="left_fake_end_joint" />
    <chain base_link="left_arm_base_link" tip_link="left_fake_end" />
</group>
<group name="right_arm">
    <joint name="right_arm_base_joint" />
    ...
    <joint name="right_fake_end_joint" />
    <chain base_link="right_arm_base_link" tip_link="right_fake_end" />
</group>
<group name="both_arms">
    <group name="left_arm" />
    <group name="right_arm" />
```

But I got this error

```
 [ERROR] []: Group 'both_arms' is not a chain
 [ERROR] []: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'both_arms'
 [ERROR] []: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group both_arms.
```

And also I tried the below configuration, as pr2 set each arm as a chain, but also got the same error.

I did a test on pr2, when I choosing arms, it will show two interactive marker for both arms.
But in my case, I don't have any, but if I choose right_arm or left_arm, there will be one interactive marker for each arm.
This is my srdf, quite similar to the pr2's.

```
<group name="left_arm">
    <chain base_link="body_link" tip_link="left_arm_link4" />
</group>
<group name="right_arm">
    <chain base_link="body_link" tip_link="right_arm_link4" />
</group>
<group name="both_arms">
    <group name="left_arm" />
    <group name="right_arm" />
</group>
```

I don't know how pr2 setup arms plan group, it would be very appreciated that someone can help me, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384826/how-to-setup-planning-group-moveit-for-dual-arm/) by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-08-25**:
Is there nothing else that is different between your robot and the PR2? What if you add the joints to your two arm groups, like in the PR2 URDF?

**Comment by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on 2021-08-28**:
Thanks! It is the same result when I change to joints.
The Kinematic Solver for the "both_arms" group is set to None, pr2 also does this if I am correct.
My question is how this None Kinematic Solver do the motion plan, or it does the motion plan for "left_arm" and "right_arm" subgroup separately instead? I have no idea now, quite confused to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why, but after I added an end effector for each arm, two interactive markers appear. So problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) with karma: 36 on 2021-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ColorJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/108142/colorj/) on 2022-06-12**:
Would you like to  share your SRDF file?